# PHP knapsack-type fantasy sports function for webapp

Tags: php, mysql, knapsack-problem

I'm building a "lineup optimizer" for a fantasy soccer webapp, and I'm stuck on one particular piece.

I'm trying to pull a "best projected lineup" based on a column in my sql table for "estimated_points", but I need to keep the lineup under a certain salary cap, which is $100.

I need to fill 15 positions, which are as follows (position ID followed by position label, and # of players per position):

```
1 (goalkeepers): 2
2 (defenders): 5
3 (midfielders): 5
4 (forwards): 3
```

11 players will be in the starting lineup, while the other 4 end up on the bench.

I'm having trouble trying to fill each spot while keeping the entire team value under the max price of $100.  Each player is assigned their own price, obviously.

Here is my sql query right now:

```
SELECT
id AS player_id,
first_name,
last_name,
position,
estimated_points_this,
price
FROM
players
ORDER BY estimated_points_this DESC, price ASC
```

So right now I'm looping through all the results, keeping track of how many players from each position I have, and my running total team value.  If I've got the max # of players in that position OR the current total team value would exceed the max team value of $100, then I skip and move onto the next player and run the same checks on them.

The problem I'm having is that one position will fill up with players who are expensive - like if I end up filling all 5 defender slots with players who cost $6.4, that leaves me with $68 for 10 more players and so on, so I always end up with only 12-13 players because at a certain point, every single player will put the team value over my max salary cap.

There are no players under $3.9 in the game, so if I get to a point where I have 12 players in my array and my total team value is $97.8 or so, it will be impossible to stuff anymore players in there since there would only be $2.2 left in the budget.

I've heard a little about the knapsack problem, but I have no idea how to implement that in my case in PHP, or if that's even the right approach here.  I need to figure a way to get a good balance of lower-priced players and higher-priced players to fill out the entire 15-man lineup without going over the salary cap.

Do I need to select one player at a time per query, by position, and do some checks on each one in a loop instead of pulling all players inside of one query?  Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simular problem and I tried to solve it like this: Its not knapsack, but it works!

knapsack.php:

```
$lineup = new LineUp();
$lineup->setSystem($system);
$lineup->budget = $budget;

$gks  = getMinPlayer(POS_GK, $lineup->gk, $where, 1);
$defs = getMinPlayer(POS_DEF, $lineup->def, $where, 1);
$mfs  = getMinPlayer(POS_MF, $lineup->mf, $where, 2);
$fors = getMinPlayer(POS_FOR, $lineup->for, $where, 1);

// ALL
$players = new Players();
$players->addPlayers($gks);
$players->addPlayers($defs);
$players->addPlayers($mfs);
$players->addPlayers($fors);

$steps = 0;
$bestteam = new Players();
$maxvalue = -5;
$squad = new LineUp();

$value = knapSack($players, $squad, 0, '');
echo '<h2>KnapSack ('.$steps.'): ' . $value . '</h2>';

echo "<h3>".$bestteam->costs()." Mio. &euro; - ".$bestteam->points()." P</h3>";
echo $bestteam->getInfo('Best');
```

api_knapsack.php:

```
define("POS_GK", 1);
define("POS_DEF", 2);
define("POS_MF", 3);
define("POS_FOR", 4);

// Aufstellung: Z.B.: 1-3-5-2
define("SYS_352", 0);
define("SYS_451", SYS_352 + 1);
define("SYS_442", SYS_451 + 1);
define("SYS_433", SYS_442 + 1);
define("SYS_343", SYS_433 + 1);

class Players {

    public $player = array();

    function addPlayers($players) {
        $this->player = array_merge( $this->player, $players->player);
    }

    function setPlayers($players) {
        $this->player = array();
        $this->addPlayers($players);
    }

    function costs() {
        $euro = 0;
        $count = count($this->player);
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if($this->player[$i]->lineup == 1) {
                $euro += $this->player[$i]->euro;
            }
        }
        return $euro;
    }

    function points() {
        $points = 0;
        $count = count($this->player);
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if($this->player[$i]->lineup == 1) {
                $points += $this->player[$i]->points;
            }
        }
        return $points;
    }

    function addToTeam($no) {
        $this->player[$no]->lineup = 1;
    }


    function getPlayer($caption) {
        $count = count($this->player);
        $result = "<h2>$caption ($count):</h2>";
        $result .= '<table class=\"striped\"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Pt.</th><th>Euro</th><th>Pos.</th><th>Club</th><th>LineUp</th></tr>';
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $result .= "<tr>".$this->player[$i]->getInfoRow()."</tr>";
        }
        $result .= "</table>";
        return $result;
    }

    function getInfo($caption) {
        $count = count($this->player);
        $inc = 0;
        $playerstext = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if($this->player[$i]->lineup == 1) {
                $inc++;
                $playerstext .= "<tr>" . $this->player[$i]->getInfoRow() . "</tr>";
            }
        }
        $result = "<h2>$caption ($inc):</h2>";
        $result .= '<table class="striped"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Pt.</th><th>Euro</th><th>Pos.</th><th>Club</th><th>LineUp</th></tr>';
        $result .= $playerstext;
        $result .= "</table>";
        return $result;
    }

    function getInfoCount($lineup, $pos) {
        $result = "<h3>";
        switch ($pos) {
            case POS_GK:
                $result .= "Goalkeeper ($lineup->gk): ";
                break;
            case POS_DEF:
                $result .= "Defense ($lineup->def): ";
                break;
            case POS_MF:
                $result .= "Midfield ($lineup->mf): ";
                break;
            case POS_FOR:
                $result .= "Forward ($lineup->for): ";
                break;
        }

        return $result . count($this->player) . '</h3>';
    }
}

class Player {
    public $name;       // Name
    public $points;     // Expected Points
    public $euro;       // Cost
    public $position;   // Position
    public $club;
    public $lineup;     // Is Player positioned in team? 0/1

    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->points = 0;
        $this->euro = 0;
        $this->position = 0;
        $this->club = 0;
        $this->lineup = 0;
    }

    function getInfoRow() {
        return "<td>$this->name</td>" .
            "<td>$this->points</td>" .
            "<td>$this->euro</td>" .
            "<td>$this->position</td>" .
            "<td>$this->club</td>" .
            "<td>$this->lineup</td>";
    }
}

class LineUp {
    public $gk;     // Goalkeeper
    public $def;    // Defense
    public $mf;     // Midfield
    public $for;    // Forward
    public $budget;

    function __construct() {
        $this->reset();
    }

    function setSystem($system)
    {
        $this->gk = 1;
        $this->def = 3;
        $this->mf = 5;
        $this->for = 2;
        switch ($system) {
            case SYS_451:
                $this->def = 4;
                $this->mf = 5;
                $this->for = 1;
                break;
            case SYS_442:
                $this->def = 4;
                $this->mf = 4;
                $this->for = 2;
                break;
            case SYS_433:
                $this->def = 4;
                $this->mf = 3;
                $this->for = 3;
                break;
            case SYS_343:
                $this->def = 3;
                $this->mf = 4;
                $this->for = 3;
                break;
        }
    }

    function reset() {
        $this->gk = 0;
        $this->def = 0;
        $this->mf = 0;
        $this->for = 0;
        $this->budget = 0;
    }

    function addPlayer($player) {
        $this->budget = $this->budget + $player->euro;
        switch ($player->position) {
            case POS_GK:
                $this->gk++;
                break;
            case POS_DEF:
                $this->def++;
                break;
            case POS_MF:
                $this->mf++;
                break;
            case POS_FOR:
                $this->for++;
                break;
        }
    }

    function full($lineup) {
        return
            ($this->gk  == $lineup->gk) and
            ($this->def == $lineup->def) and
            ($this->mf  == $lineup->mf) and
            ($this->for == $lineup->for);
    }

    function fuller($lineup) {
        return
            ($this->gk  > $lineup->gk) or
            ($this->def > $lineup->def) or
            ($this->mf  > $lineup->mf) or
            ($this->for > $lineup->for);
    }

    function costly($lineup) {
        return (($this->budget) > ($lineup->budget));
        //var_dump($this);
        //var_dump($lineup);
        //return true;
    }
}

function getMinPlayer($pos, $count, $where, $add) {

    $players = new Players();

    $whereClause = "PositionID = $pos " . $where;

    $sql  = "Select B.* from (Select * from View_Kicker where $whereClause";
    $sql .= " order by Punkte desc limit 0, " . ($count + $add);
    $sql .= ") B order by B.Euro desc";
    $erg = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($adr = mysql_fetch_array($erg)) {
        $player = new Player($adr['Name']);
        $player->points = $adr['Punkte'];
        $player->euro = $adr['Euro'];
        $player->position = $pos;
        $players->player[] = $player;
    }
    return $players;
}

function getPlayer($pos, $count, $where) {

    $players = new Players();

    $whereClause = "PositionID = $pos " . $where;

    $sql  = "Select * from View_Kicker where $whereClause";
    $sql .= " and PunkteVJ > 0";
    $sql .= " order by Euro";
    $erg = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($adr = mysql_fetch_array($erg)) {

        $euro = $adr['Euro'];
        $points = $adr['PunkteVJ'];

        $sql2 = mysql_query("Select count(*) as Anz from View_Kicker where $whereClause  and Euro < $euro and PunkteVJ > $points");
        $erg2 = mysql_fetch_object($sql2);
        $no = $erg2->Anz;

        if ($no < $count) {
            $player = new Player($adr['Name']);
            $player->points = $adr['PunkteVJ'];
            $player->euro = $adr['Euro'] * 10;
            $player->position = $pos;
            $players->player[] = $player;
        }
    }
    return $players;
}

/**
 * @param $players      - all players to handle
 * @param $squad        - actual lineup ( how many players are in team)
 * @param $count        - whicht player to handle
 * @param $deep         - only for output
 * @return int|mixed
 */
function knapSack($players, $squad, $count, $deep) {
    global $lineup; // global lineup like 3-5-2 and 42.5mio budget
    global $steps;  // only for output: method requests
    global $bestteam;
    global $maxvalue;
    $steps++;

    //echo '<br>No.: ' . $steps . ' ('.$deep.')';

    // Last Child in Tree
    if ($count > count($players->player) - 1) {
        //echo ' -3';
        return -3;
    }
    // actual Team to expensive
    if ($squad->costly($lineup)) {
        //echo ' -2';
        return -2;
    }
    // Team to full
    if ($squad->fuller($lineup)) {
        //echo ' -1';
        return -1;
    }
    // PERFECT TEAM
    if ($squad->full($lineup)) {
        $points = $players->points();
        if ($points > $maxvalue) {
            $maxvalue = $points;
            $bestteam->setPlayers($players);
        }
        return $points;
    }
    // To many players from a club
    //TODO

    $player = $players->player[$count];
   // echo '- handle '.$player->name.' ('.$count.')<br>';

    $newplayers = unserialize(serialize($players));
    $newsquad   = unserialize(serialize($squad));

    $newplayers->addToTeam($count);
    $newsquad->addPlayer($player);

    return max(
        knapSack($players, $squad, $count + 1, $deep . '0'),  // Add Player NOT to team
        knapSack($newplayers, $newsquad, $count + 1, $deep . '1') // Add Player to team
    );
}
```

Now it works, but it cant handle big data [players] in browser. If you want, we can improve the algorithm together.